# I don't want to send empty email if no results found

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, email

I have used cursor to loop through my values and Every time i am sending a mail but  if no result found then it was sending an empty mail,How can i avoid that?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Sql Server 2008

Comment: for some reasons i am unable to put the source code here

Comment: Well, `for some reasons i am unable to provide any assistance here` :) .. Its really hard to see what you should do differently if we don't know what you are doing :)

Comment: I am using SET @tableHTML  where i have tr and th and i have executed  a query based on this i am sending mail everytime

Comment: You might want to post your SQL here anyway. Your statement *"cursor to loop through my values" sounds like an awful idea. SQL is a Query Language, not a programming language; it doesn't do looping well.

Comment: @Larnu actually cursor loop is a great solution when using sql to send mail

Comment: @t-clausen.dk depends what the OP means here. if they mean generate data, send an email, generate data, send an email, that's fine. If they mean loop to generate data, send (a singular) email, that's a bad idea. It's unclear, and hence why I asked them to share.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much guessed logic, but based on  the very vague comments and question, I imagine you simply need to use an `IF`. This is Pseudo-SQL, however...

```
DECLARE @TableHTML varchar(MAX);

SELECT @TableHTML = {Your HTML data expression};

IF @TableHTML IS NOT NULL BEGIN

    EXEC sp_send_dbmail @Subject = {Your Subject},
                        @Body = @TableHTML,
                        @....;
END
```